# How to import highlight.js on react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlight.js

I would like to display and highlight some "JSON" data in a React.js component.

It works, but the problem is when the component refresh, the highlighted code disappear.

I want to clarify that I'm a newbie here.

Thank you for your support.

```
import React from "react";

import hljs from "highlight.js";
import "highlight.js/styles/github.css";
import json from "highlight.js/lib/languages/json";
hljs.registerLanguage("json", json);
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

const JsonViewer = props => {
  return (
    <pre>
      <code className="json">
         {JSON.stringify(props.content, null, 2)}
      </code>
    </pre>
  );
};

export default JsonViewer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution by integrate [react-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight).

You can use `innerHtml` to true on the property.

```js
import Highlight from "react-highlight"
import "highlight.js/styles/gradient-dark.css"; // import style on the root file
import JSONViewer from "./JSONViewer"

<Highlight innerHTML className="w-full">
  <JSONViewer content={yourContentHere} />
</Highlight>
```

Set `innerHTML=true` to highlight multiple code snippets at a time. This is especially usefull if html with multiple code snippets is generated from preprocesser tools like markdown.

> Warning: If innerHTML is set to true, make sure the html generated
> with code snippets is from trusted source.

Using `hljs.registerLanguage("json", json);` or `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` will getting a problem by rerendering react. It's not recall when using dependency but `useEffect` without dependency like this it works.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); // it works, but bad for performance because will call every single time re-rendering.
})

useEffect(() => {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); // it doesn't works
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I see the function call `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` is the one activating the highlighting. If you are using hooks call that function in `useEffect` or if you are using classes call it in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.